# JDBC to Google Sheet - Start at specific MySQL row. (Prevent extra server load)

Tags: google-apps-script

My code is working just fine, but it is clear that it goes through each row in the database each run. This needs to run every minute so I'm concerned with the server load that this may create. (And the speed)

Since this pulls in the MySQL row ID I'm trying to have it start at the row after the last. Nothing I've hacked together has worked.

**Here is my code:**

```
function pull2() {
   // make the connection
 var connection = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://111.222.333.444:3306/dbname", "user", "pass");

   // perform the query
 var SQLstatement = connection.createStatement();
 var result = SQLstatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM messages");


   // choose a range in sheet
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var cell = ss.getRange('A2');


   // loop through result object, setting cell values to database data
 var row = 0;
 while(result.next()) {
    for(var i=0; i<13; i++) {     // 13 fields per record
       cell.offset(row, i).setValue(result.getString(i+1));
    }
    row++;




 }
   // tidy up
 result.close();
 SQLstatement.close();
 connection.close();
}
```

Code from:
http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/drivebunny/connecting-to-mysql-databases-using-apps-script/

Google Developers Info:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

Comment: This is not related really to apps script. Its a regular sql quesion thou i see youve made no attempt to modify the query string. Attempt modification instead of asking for the code And then show us your modified code and whats not working.

Comment: Seemed like it was about telling the script to start at a particular place in the table, so that is why I thought that would be where to start.  I didn't modify the code further as I read for two hours on this subject and just don't get how to do it.

Comment: Not enough info here to help you. If you have a timestamp or autoincrement id you could sorr by that and start from there next time. You do need to know how to use sql for this.